# how to make combo box selection

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am creating a form in access where I have certain combo boxes.The selection made in one combo box limits or filters the available options in other combo boxes based on that selection.

So all the 5 combo boxes that I have on this form depend on the selection made on that 6th main/anchor combo box selection.

But if i don't make any selection in this first/main combo box, i see no values in other combo boxes.

Is it possible to leave the main combo box unselected and still see values in other combo boxes and make selection as desired ?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have done?

Comment: I added 6 combo boxes on my form using the controls in the design tab. And then values for 5 other combo box fields depends on the selection made in the first combo box. I used the macro requery after update and added the criteria(address/value of the main combo box) for other 5 combo boxes.If i make a selection in the main/first combo box, everything works fine and the values are filtered in the other 5 combo boxes. But my question is, if don't make any selection in the main/first combo box, i see no values in other 5 combo boxes and that is something i want to fix.